# VSCode and Python: Run lint on demand

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to run lint inside VSCode. But I don't want it to run constantly and provide real-time feedback, because it is too distracting. Instead, I want to run it only when I press a button. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: so you mean to have a linter extension only show problems for the currently active editor? It's not clear to me exactly what is being asked for here.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I want a linter that is integrated with vscode but is only invoked when I click a button (instead of running constantly and generating noise).